# Wagtail show other related pages from the same group as the current page

Tags: wagtail

I cannot work out the required template code for showing a list of other lessons in the same group as the current lesson.

I've used the excellent 'Learn Wagtail' tutorials to create a model largely equivalent to the blog model except I've extended it with a page for grouping different lesson pages using an orderable so they can be rearranged.

LessonGroupOrderable - Orderable with LessonGroupPage as the parent (related name = 'group_lessons'). FK to LessonDetailPage so they can be added and re-ordered.

LessonGroupPage - Course/topic title/details plus InlinePanel ('group_lessons')

LessonDetailPage - Page with lesson content

On the LessonDetailPage template, how do I get all groups (and lessons) that the current page is in so I can display a related lessons list?

Comment: Could you share the code for your models to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Apologies, I know what you mean, I was going to post it but with all the other bits in there it seemed to make it more complex. I'll try the answer below then post the code if necessary.

Comment: No worries - I would suggest you post the code either way, as might help someone else. By all means just include the models and the fields for Parental/Foreignkey relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming as an example that `LessonGroupOrderable` has a field named `lesson_detail_page` then the following query should get you the relevant groups for a page:

```
groups = LessonGroup.objects.filter(group_lessons__lesson_detail_page=page)
```

I would suggest that you provide the list of groups to your template using `get_context` on the `LessonDetailPage` model, rather than directly in your template, just to keep the business logic out of the way so:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)

    context['groups'] = list(LessonGroup.objects.filter(group_lessons__lesson_detail_page=self))

    return context
```

Then in your LessonDetailPage template:

```
<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>{{ group.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it answered exactly what I wanted. Can I ask, why did you use 'list(LessonGroup.obj....)' command instead of 'LessonGroup.obj...' which seems to work without 'list' in front of it as well?

Comment: No profound reason, just personal preference to pass simple data into templates where possible, so evaluated the queryset into a list of page objects. Glad it helped.